# In Postman tests, how do I generate a schema from dynamic JSON?

Tags: json, testing, schema, postman, postman-collection-runner

In Postman I want to be able to compare two different environments responses.

First I want to fetch data from the first environment, save the response JSON to an environment variable or a global variable. Then fetch data from the second one, and assert that the JSON from the first fetch has the exact same schema, as the JSON from the second fetch.

Postman doesn't appear to have a 'schema generator' API, so that I could dynamically generate schemas for comparison from the JSON that I receive.

Are there any other ways I could possible resolve this issue with?

Comment: QuickType.io will generate a variety of code related things from actual sample JSON

Comment: @CaiusJard I think this could be useful if I was looking to make this an 'app'. But the idea would be to keep it inside postman tests.

Comment: I have exact same requirement and I can't find any good solution. please help.

Comment: @DilipAgheda Sorry didn't actually find a good solution to this, at least not with postman.